# The cd command on macOS performs an ls after dc. Why?

Tags: bash, cd-command

On MacOS terminal with bash, I get an ls after a cd. When the directory contains many files, I can't see the effect of the cd since it scrolls away due to the ls.

This is what I see

```
$ which cd
cd is a function
cd () 
{ 
    builtin cd "$@";
    ls -FGlAhp
}
cd is a shell builtin
cd is /usr/bin/cd
```

How I can I avoid this ? Is this function standard on the mac or was it installed by some application ? How can I know ?

I usually work with Ubuntu which doesn't behave this way. It is disturbing.

Comment: Possibly rename it like `cdls` so `cd` reverts to a built-in, but you can reinstate your function or use it with the new name.

Comment: @Quasímodo You were right except that on mac there is not .bashrc, just a .bash_profile file. It was defined there with other aliases and function definitions "to make the terminal better" as it is said in the comment.

Comment: macOS didn't put it there, something you installed did.  As for bash_profile vs bashrc, well, that's what the INVOCATION section of the man page is for.